# Does a complex extending xs:anyType allow textual content?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have the following complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="ValuePropertyType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
            <xs:attribute name="recordCount" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Does it allow plain simple textual content? Like:

```
<my:values>
2007-04-01T00:00:00.000-06:00,30.4,28.8,155.8,1055.32,55,haze
2007-04-01T00:00:10.000-06:00,30.4,28.8,155.8,1055.4,59,haze
</my:values>
```

I think it does, but finding a normative reference in the XML Schema spec is quite... hard.

I ask also because JAXB XJC generates the following property here:

```
@XmlAnyElement
protected List<Element> any;
```

Which only expects elements. I think it should allow text as well.

**Update**

Xerces, Eclipse (whatever it uses underneath), Stylus Studio and Oxygen validated [this example](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/scripts/tests/OM/1.0.0/weatherObservation.xml#L24-L48) against [this schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/om/1.0.0/om.xsd). Specifically, this is the [complex type](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/schemas/src/main/resources/ogc/sweCommon/1.0.1/aggregateTypes.xsd#L137-L147) in question:

```
<xs:complexType name="DataValuePropertyType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Use to point or include data values inline</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
            <xs:attribute name="recordCount" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="gml:AssociationAttributeGroup"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition can be found in part 1 of the XML Schema specification, in §2.2.1.1 [XML Schema 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-urType), [XML Schema 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#key-anyType) and §3.4.7 [XML Schema 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e9252), [XML Schema 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#builtin-ctd). Depending on the version, the wording is a bit different but in the end it is similar.

It is more clear in version 1.1 that `anyType` is a mixed content, so it allows at the same time textual content and tags in it.

Since your `complexContent` is an extension of this mixed content, it is also a mixed content type.

It however seems a bit weird to provide an extensions on the basis of `anyType`, since it already allows any content, and also any attribute. In the specification, if you look at §3.4.7, it is mentioned that the *derivation method* is **restriction**.

Answer (score 3):

A complex type with `complexContent` does not allow text content as children unless it is declared `mixed="true"`. If you make it mixed then it allows arbitrary text nodes mixed in amongst whatever elements the content model allows, you can't restrict the text to be of a specific type (unless you use `simpleContent`, but that then doesn't allow child elements at all).

Comment: I've just checked my example in question [weatherObservation.xml](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/scripts/tests/OM/1.0.0/weatherObservation.xml) against [om.xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/om/1.0.0/om.xsd) using [xsdv](https://github.com/amouat/xsd-validator), it validated. I'll try other tools.

Comment: Stylus Studio and Eclipse also validated the document without problems.

Comment: Hm, Oxygen also says it's valid... I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 2):

@potame has already given the correct answer, before I did. But since

> finding a normative reference in the XML Schema spec is quite... hard

I'd like to give you such a reference on-site, instead of links to the specs.

So, if the `base` attribute of your `xs:extension` has the value `xs:anyType`, everything is allowed as its content, prior to the restriction. The spec is indeed vague on this, good references are

> [...] *anyType* which allows any children and/or character data content, and any attributes, as long as it is well-formed XML.

<sup>Walmsley, Priscilla. Definitive XML Schema. The Charles F. Goldfarb Definitive XML Series. Prentice Hall: 2012. P 97.</sup>

> *anyType* is a generic complex type that allows anything; any attributes, any child elements, any text content.

<sup>Walmsley, Priscilla. Definitive XML Schema. The Charles F. Goldfarb Definitive XML Series. Prentice Hall: 2012. P 203.</sup>

---

Then, a note on schema design: Defining complex types as extensions of `xs:anyType` results in a lax (i.e. not very strict) XML Schema document. In practice, this means that the set of documents that are valid according to the resulting schema is much larger than necessary - and the schema does not give fine-grained control over the structures in documents.

An XML Schema like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:attributeGroup name="AssociationAttributeGroup">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

    <xs:element name="item" type="DataValuePropertyType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="DataValuePropertyType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Use to point or include data values inline</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:attribute name="recordCount" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="AssociationAttributeGroup"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

does not even require that the attributes that are expressly defined in the extension body really appear in an input document, since they lack a `use` attribute, whose default value is `"optional"`.

Comment: Thank you for the references! Very good answer. I did not design this schema, also found the construct... peculiar.

Comment: @Mathias Müller Thank you also for the reference, I'll try to get a copy. I use van der Vlist's "*XML Schema*" (O'Reilly), but `anyType` definition is a bit too concise in this book. And it is not up-to-date with XML Schema 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale for the JAXB handling of `anyType` can be found in section 6.3.3 of the JAXB ([JSR-22](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) specification and quoted below:

```
6.3.3xsd:anyType

xsd:anyType is the root of the type definition hierarchy for a schema. All
complex type definitions in a schema implicitly derive from xsd:anyType.
Given that the JAXB 2.0 architecture does not define a common base class for
all JAXB class bindings of complex type definitions, the only possible binding
property base type binding for xsd:anyType is to java.lang.Object.
This binding enables all possible type and element substitutions for an element
of type xsd:anyType.

CODE EXAMPLE 6-1 Binding of element with type xsd:anyType

<xs:element name="anyContent/> <!--@type defaults to xs:anyType-->
    <xs:complexType name="base">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="anyContent/>
            <xs:element name="anyContentAgain" type="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

public class Base {
    void setAnyContent(Object obj);
    Object getAnyContent();
    void setAnyContentAgain(Object obj);
    Object getAnyContentAgain();
}

A schema author defines an element to be of type xs:anyType to defer
constraining an element to a particular type to the xml document author.
Through the use of xsi:type attribute or element substitution, an xml
document author provides constraints for an element defined as xs:anyType.
The JAXB unmarshaller is able to unmarshal a schema defined xsd:anyType
element that has been constrained within the xml document to an easy to access
JAXB mapped class. However, when the xml document does not constrain the
xs:anyType element, JAXB unmarshals the unconstrained content to an
element node instance of a supported DOM API.

Type substitution is covered in more detail in Section 6.7.4.1 and 6.7.4.2.
Element substitution is covered in more detail in Section 6.7.5.
```

Comment: Interesting; for people (like me) who know XSD but not JAXB - could you also explain why JAXB XJC (allegedly, see above) interprets a complex XSD type extended from xs:anyType as _not_ allowing textual content?

Comment: @MathiasMüller This is well reproducible with XJC. And adding `mixed="true"` to the complex type makes it `List<Serializable>` instead of `List<Element>` thus allowing textual content. I'd consider this to be a bug. Either in XJC or in the JAXB spec.

Comment: @lexicore I do not doubt that anyType extensions generate `List<Element>` properties - or your expertise. I meant to use "allegedly" in the sense that I do not have the means and knowledge to reproduce it myself. I agree - this appears to be inconsistent with the XSD spec, but perhaps Blaise has an explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: @MathiasMüller No worries, I absolutely did not take "allegedly" as offence of any kind. :) Sorry if it looked like that. My point was primarily about `mixed="true"`.